# Where is the Fixedsys font in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, fonts

I'm trying to locate the font Fixedsys in Windows Vista. I understand it's a hidden system font?

My main goal at the end of the day is to get Google Chrome to display Fixedsys (should the CSS file ask for it), and the TrueType replacements I found so far don't look the same...

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to believe with the thousands of TrueType fonts out there, that you can't find one as ugly. Especially the  clone mentioned on wikipedia, "Fixedsys Excelsior" (although they warn you that you must have it at 12pt - to match the original - or else it looks bad) http://www.fixedsysexcelsior.com/

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer at http://old.nabble.com/Fixedsys-font-td17225057.html. Basically the fixedsys font is vgafix.fon. For higher resoulutions there is 8514fix.fon. I have also more variants 8514fixe.fon, 8514fixg.fon, etc.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this free version of 'fixedsys': http://fixedsys.moviecorner.de/?l=1. just place the ttf font into your (or the systems) font folder.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this font doesn't look the same as the system font (I tried this approach before, it was the bit I mentioned in the second paragraph of my question).